# How can count all RSI bars over 70 and under 30?

Tags: mql4

I want to count rsi bars under or over 70 and 30 .
rsi oversold and bought area are sometime very strong in momentum.they not come back immediately as usual know.
So I want to count if RSI Bars over and under 70 30 for 5 bars. open orders
I code like that

```html
     for(int i = 0; i<20 ;i++)
     {
       rsi1 = iRSI(Symbol(),0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);
        Print("RSI1 is "+rsi1+"");
       rsi2 = iRSI(Symbol(),0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,i+2);
        Print("RSI2 is "+rsi2+"");
       rsi3 = iRSI(Symbol(),0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,i+3);
        Print("RSI3 is "+rsi3+"");
       rsi4 = iRSI(Symbol(),0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,i+4);
        Print("RSI4 is "+rsi4+"");
     }
    
     if(OrdersTotal() == 0 ){
    if( rsi1 > 70 && rsi2 > 70 && rsi3 > 70 && rsi4 > 70 )
     OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,1,MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_ASK),3,0,0,"Main Buy",1111,0,Green);//this is rabbit
    
     if( rsi1 < 30 && rsi2 < 30 && rsi3 < 30 && rsi4 < 30 )
     OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,1,MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_BID),3,0,0,"Main Sell",1111,0,Red);//this is rabbit
```

But in actual it does not count 5 bars
only count 1 bars and open orders.
How can solve it.
Please someone help me.

[image]

[image]

want to count from here to here .

Comment: The `for` loop is overriding the values on each iteration. In the end you have the values for 19+1, 19+2, 19+3 and so on. What is the purpose of the for loop?

Comment: loop for bars counts bro. 0+1 , 1+1,2+1, etc... to count RSI last bars over under 70 30 level .what wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `for` loop, this is not an indicator and you are not working with historical data. If you want to check the last 5 closed candles your code should be:

```
   double rsi1 = iRSI(NULL,0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,1); Print("RSI1 is "+rsi1);
   double rsi2 = iRSI(NULL,0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,2); Print("RSI2 is "+rsi2);
   double rsi3 = iRSI(NULL,0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,3); Print("RSI3 is "+rsi3);
   double rsi4 = iRSI(NULL,0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,4); Print("RSI4 is "+rsi4);
   double rsi5 = iRSI(NULL,0,10,PRICE_CLOSE,5); Print("RSI5 is "+rsi5);

   if(OrdersTotal() == 0 )
   {
      if(rsi1>70 && rsi2>70 && rsi3>70 && rsi4>70 && rsi5>70)
      OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,1,Ask,3,0,0,"Main Buy",1111,0,clrGreen);

      if(rsi1<30 && rsi2<30 && rsi3<30 && rsi4<30 && rsi5<30)
      OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,1,Bid,3,0,0,"Main Sell",1111,0,clrRed);
   }
```